# SQL how to filter A table with Two ranges in another table

Tags: sql, range, inner-join

I have a table with Bills, each Bill can have 20 subregister.

Example (Top 5 Per Bill, could be up to 60,000 bills)

(TABLE ONE)

```
Bill |   SubRow   |
-----+------------+
1000 |     1      |
1000 |     2      |
1000 |     3      |  
1000 |     4      |
1000 |     5      | 
1001 |     1      |  
1001 |     2      | 
1001 |     3      |  
1001 |     4      |  
1001 |     5      |
```

In another table, I have the Bill number and a Range of subrows

Example: 
(TABLE TWO)

```
Bill | InitialRange | Final Range|
-----+--------------+------------+
1000 |     1        |      2     |
1000 |     4        |      5     |
1001 |     3        |      5     |
```

In a query I want to achieve the following:

To show , from table One, all records NOT beetween the ranges in table 2.

That means I should get the following set :

```
Bill |    SubRow  |
-----+------------+
1000 |     3      |
1001 |     1      |
1001 |     2      |
```

What I have so far:

```
Select  Bill,SubRow 
 from TABLE ONE     
    LEFT  join TABLE TWO ON  TABLEONE.Bill= TABLETWO.bill
    where  Subrow < InitialRange and Subrow > FinalRange
```

but the second condition in the second row in TABLETWO overrides the first for the 1000 bill.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

note(I the tables appears messed up, I will try to fix it)

Image with Example:

http://postimg.org/image/ymc3z2uzx/

Comment: Well, tables are messed up. Fixi'n them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_TWO 
WHERE TABLE_ONE.Bill = TABLE_TWO.Bill 
AND TABLE_ONE.SubRow BETWEEN TABLE_TWO.IinitialRange AND TABLE_TWO.FinalRange)
```

Comment: AWESOOME!!! I had been struggling with that for the last 2 days...
Thank you VERY MUCH, Mikhail